# JQUERY onclick link opens as "undefined" blank page

Tags: jquery

Need quick help!! Created a script for below HTML container click event.

1. When i click second  tag with `<h3></h3><p></p>`, link opens in same window without any error.
2. But, first tag with images shows url with "http://www.url.com/undefined"

Need a solution to open exact link like second `<a>` tag element.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="isotope-tile ng-scope isotope-tile--large" data-isotope-tile="{modifier:'large', order:{mobile:1, desktop:1}}" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="parbase teaser tile-1">
    <div id="_content_sites_sg_en_personal_discover_jcr_content_par_landing_tiles_tile-1" class="campaign ">
        <div class="parbase tile section" style=""> 
            <div id="filler-tile-1">
                <a href="legacy.html" class="tm-blue tileEle">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="image.jpg">
                        <img class="icon" src="badge.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="legacy.html" class="content" onclick="ga('send','event', 'tile', 'clickthrough', 'Legacy',{'dimension6':'legacy'});">
                    <h3>TM Legacy</h3>
                    <p>TM Legacy secures financial protection and peace of mind that lasts beyond your lifetime. </p>
                </a>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.isotope-tile a.tm-blue').click(function(e) { 
     e.stopPropagation();
});


$("div.isotope-tile").each( function()
{
    $(this).click(function(event)
    {
        if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
            location.href = $(event.target).parent().attr("href");
        }
        else{
            location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why not `$("div.isotope-tile").click(function(event)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first tag when you click on

```
 <img src="image.jpg">
```

The jquery code in IF condiotion execute

```
 if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
        location.href = $(event.target).parent().attr("href");
    }
```

jquery code try to find out the href tag in patent of image tag. and parent of image tag is

```
<div class="image">
```

It does not contain href tag. so it gives undefined value.

So your jquery code in if condition should be

```
if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
        location.href = $(event.target).parent().parent().attr("href");
    }
```

I Think It will help you. Please let me know if there is still any issue

Your jquery code can be write as

```
$("div.isotope-tile").each( function()
{
    $(this).click(function(event)
    {
        if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
            location.href = $(event.target).closest("a").attr("href");
        }
        else{
           location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Lokesh, Thanks for your reply. I tried adding "parent().parent()" earlier. It works fine for image element.. but getting undefined for "<h3></h3><p></p>". is it possible to seperate code for these each <a> tag inside the container? have multiple "isotope-tile" container.

Comment: You can try     location.href = $(event.target).closest("a").attr("href"); Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks.. it works!! Thanks for your great help!! Can you please update your answer to make your solution as answer?

Comment: $('.isotope-tile a.tm-blue').click(function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
    });


 $("div.isotope-tile").each( function()
 {
  $(this).click(function(event)
  {
            if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
             location.href = $(event.target).closest("a").attr("href");
            }
            else{
             location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
            }
  });
 });

Comment: Can you please confirm the code is correct?  "<h3></h3><p></p>".link on iphone6 opens in new window. sorry to trouble you.